# How do I resolve the message "No such file or directory" after installing rbenv on Mac OS?

Tags: ruby, bash, macos, rbenv

When opening my Terminal and/or using an IDE to write code, I get the following message:

```
-bash: export PATH="/Users/ryananding/.rbenv/shims:${PATH}"
export RBENV_SHELL=bash
source '/usr/local/Cellar/rbenv/1.1.2/libexec/../completions/rbenv.bash'
command rbenv rehash 2>/dev/null
rbenv() {
local command
command="${1:-}"
if [ "$#" -gt 0 ]; then
    shift
fi

case "$command" in
rehash|shell)
    eval "$(rbenv "sh-$command" "$@")";;
*)
    command rbenv "$command" "$@";;
esac
}: No such file or directory
```

I have followed the instructions found on https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv and the rbenv doctor doesn't show any errors. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please provide the rbenv related content in `~/.bash_profile`, `~/.bashrc`.

Answer (score 17):

I solved it in the following way.

```
$ rbenv rehash
```

Answer (score -1):

This line fails during loading of bash

```
source '/usr/local/Cellar/rbenv/1.1.2/libexec/../completions/rbenv.bash
```

You need to set right path to `rbenv.bash` file from `/completions` folder 
To find the folder do:

1. Find version of your rbenv `rbenv --version` => `1.1.2`
2. Here you should see `/completions` folder `ls -la /usr/local/Cellar/rbenv/1.1.2/`
3. Set right path to `rbenv.bash` file in your `.bash_profile` which is `source '/usr/local/Cellar/rbenv/1.1.2/completions/rbenv.bash'`

Answer (score -1):

Try to check your rbenv directory on terminal.

1. `ls -la /usr/local/Cellar/rbenv` list rbenv version. For me personly, there is **1.2.0** instaed of **1.1.2** . If there is no rbenv version, using `brew install rbenv ruby-build` [1](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv)
2. Rewrite the following command in your bash_profile, make sure replace 1.x.x to your rbenv version. `source '/usr/local/Cellar/rbenv/1.x.x/libexec/../completions/rbenv.bash'`
3. `source ~/.bash_profile`